# BNC terminator at end of T junction

Tags: bnc

I'm planning to get an oscilloscope and a signal generator.

It seems to connect the signal generator to the oscilloscope. And it seems a 50 ohms terminator is needed.

I wonder if I can use a BNC T junction, and put the terminator on one end, and the other end with a cable towards the oscilloscope, or should the terminator be inside the chain?

Comment: which signal frequencies are we talking about? Also, "T-junction" is a bit too unspecific, there's different kind of things that can happen in one of these, and you might and will screw up your measurements if you don't know what kind of junction (power splitter) you're using.

Comment: Most signal generators don't *need* to be terminated unless driving a long cable. "Long" as in wavelength.

Comment: @MarcusMüller well I don't have specific specifications, I'm new to signal generators, but following an electronics course and so far I'm only able to use the test signal from the oscilliscope. I also am not aware of different type of t-junctions.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I also just read in the accepted answer. I'm not intending to use a long cable (well default cable I guess).

Comment: Sometimes just a short leaded 1/4W 49.9R works ok inside the BNC T at DSO end which works OK up to 0.5GHz  But AC couple if viewing SMPS  ripple  but higher BW DSO's should have it built-n

Comment: If you don't put a terminator on the line be careful about the calibration of the signal generator - the output voltage setting normally assumes a terminator and will be twice the value if there is no terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually signal generators have 50 ohm source impedance so it can drive BNC coax just fine. Some oscilloscopes have built-in 50 ohm termination too, so external termination is not needed. If the oscilloscope needs external termination, just put T junction to scope, one end to coax and one end to terminator.

Comment: Agreed.  If external 50 ohm (parallel) termination is needed, always put it as close to the destination (the 'scope in this case) as possible.